# C#: Binary Operator Overloading : Without containing type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overriding, binary-operators

Is there anyway to overload a binary operator without have the containing type or using an extension method?

I want to override the `==` operator between two byte arrays, and hopefully, without an extension method.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely impossible; extension operators do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it impossible, but it sounds downright dangerous. This is exactly why they limited operator overloading unlike C++. They give you a lot of the expressiveness that operators allow, but avoid many of the pitfalls that C++ provided.

The number of people that would do this and cause unexpected results for their fellow developers would probably be scary.

Create a method.